# Android Studio: How to get EditText values from Fragment 1 to Fragment 2 respectively on button clicked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to get the edited information from Fragment 1 to Fragment 2 when a button is clicked.

To edit the details (need to be on `Profile` page first, by clicking on the `image view` at the `navigation drawer header`):

1. Landing page is `Profile (Fragment2)`
2. Click `Edit` button to go to `Edit Profile (Fragment1)`
3. `Edit Profile (Fragment1)` will be shown
4. Edit the information
5. Click `Done`
6. `Profile (Fragment2)` will display the details that are edited

Here is the code:

**MainActivity** where **Fragment2** is able to be opened using the navigation drawer header

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
//        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View header_view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) header_view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame
                                , profile)
                        .commit();
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

    }
```

**EditProfile (Fragment1)**

```
public class EditProfile extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    View myView; //A view object called myView

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editprofile, container, false);
        Button btn = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.btnEPDone);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText editName = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.editName);
                EditText editDate = (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.editDOB);

                Profile profile = new Profile();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("name", editName.getText().toString());
                args.putString("date", editDate.getText().toString());
                profile.setArguments(args);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame
                                , profile)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
        return myView;
    }
}
```

**Profile(Fragment2)**

```
public class Profile extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    View myView; //A view object called myView

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
        TextView txtName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.viewName);
        txtName.setText(getArguments().getString("name"));
        TextView txtDate = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.viewDOB);
        txtDate.setText(getArguments().getString("date"));
        Button btn = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.btnVPDone);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame
                                , new EditProfile())
                        .commit();
            }
        });
        return myView;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
    11/26 16:19:41: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p com.example.hci /Users/Desktop/HCI/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_9.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.hci/com.example.hci.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 4411 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x944c8f00: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x944c8f00: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf637820)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x944c8f00: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf637820)
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=11KB, data=20KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=11KB, data=20KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=11KB, data=38KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=11KB, data=38KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=91KB, data=57KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=89KB, data=43KB
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.hci, PID: 4411
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.hci.Profile.onCreateView(Profile.java:31)
                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2508)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1279)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2407)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2186)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2142)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2043)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:719)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Application terminated.
```

[Solved] After I edited both name and date in Fragment1, both text view of name and date showed the edited date instead of name and date respectively in Fragment2.

I edit the details (name and date) and on button clicked, the details are displayed on fragment 2 (Profile). After viewing the details at fragment2 (Profile), I want to edit again, but this time I edited only one detail (i.e. date). After clicking the button in fragment 1 (Edit Profile), text view (date) is updated but text view (name) is blank in fragment 2 (Profile).

Is it possible to save the 1st edit details, and display it after a 2nd edit was made?

The app crashes when I click on the navigation drawer header to go to `Profile (Fragment2)`

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

You could use extra arguments to pass parameters:

Fragment 1

```
      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    EditText editName = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.editName);          
                    EditText editDate = (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.editDOB);

                    Profile profile = new Profile();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("name", editName.getText().toString());
                    args.putString("date", editDate.getText().toString());
                    profile.setArguments(args);
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                                    , profile)
                            .commit();
                }
            });
```

Fragment 2

```
      @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
            TextView txtName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.viewName);
            txtName.setText(getArguments().getString("name"));
            TextView txtDate = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.viewDOB);
            txtDate.setText(getArguments().getString("date"));
            Button btn = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.btnVPDone);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                                    , new EditProfile())
                            .commit();
                }
            });
            return myView;
        }
```

Comment: I have edited my question, if i'm using a navigation drawer header to open `fragment 2 (Profile)` first, then going to `fragment 1 (Edit Profile)` by clicking the edit button, and pass the values to `fragment 2 (Profile)`after it is done. Will the above code work?

Comment: Yes , try the my solution

Comment: I tried it, but when I open `fragment 2` from navigation drawer header, the app crashes

Comment: Put your logcat to see the crash

Comment: Dont forget to use FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();fragmentManager.beginTransaction() .replace(R.id.content_frame , profile) , not new Profile()

Comment: I have added the logcat in my question

Comment: I've edited the code in my question with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Your ProfileFragment class should have static method which accepts Bundle as parameter like this:

```
public static ProfileFragment newInstance(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

In Your EditProfileFragment , you should call this :

```
ProfileFragment profile = ProfileFragment.newInstance(bundleValues);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame
        , profile)
        .commit();
```